Provision a SharePoint Document Library with DOcuments (JS FIles) in it using SPFx web part
We have a requirement to Provision a SharePoint Document Library with Documents (JS FIles) in it using the SPFx web part.
There are several JS, and CSS files that I want to provision at the time of the SPFx web part installation.
I have tried different ways like reading the file but to no avail.
The Files are stored under the Src/Assets folder.
Any help is appreciated.
